# Lista despegable

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy creando esta lista asi :

```css
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

.form-signin {
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

    .form-signin .form-signin-heading, .form-signin .checkbox {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .form-signin .checkbox {
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .form-signin .form-control {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

        .form-signin .form-control:focus {
            z-index: 2;
        }

    .form-signin input[type="text"] {
        margin-bottom: -1px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }

    .form-signin input[type="password"] {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }

.account-wall {
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.login-title {
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
}

.profile-img {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    display: block;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.need-help {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.new-account {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

/* remove outer padding */
.main .row {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*Remove rounded coners*/

nav.sidebar.navbar {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

nav.sidebar, .main {
    -webkit-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
    transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
}

/* Add gap to nav and right windows.*/
.main {
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

/* .....NavBar: Icon only with coloring/layout.....*/

/*small/medium side display*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    /*Allow main to be next to Nav*/
    .main {
        position: absolute;
        width: calc(100% - 40px); /*keeps 100% minus nav size*/
        margin-left: 40px;
        float: right;
    }

    /*lets nav bar to be showed on mouseover*/
    nav.sidebar:hover + .main {
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

    /*Center Brand*/
    nav.sidebar.navbar.sidebar > .container .navbar-brand, .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    /*Center Brand*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-brand, nav.sidebar .navbar-header {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    /*Center Icons*/
    nav.sidebar a {
        padding-right: 13px;
    }

    /*adds border top to first nav box */
    nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li:first-child {
        border-top: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
    }

    /*adds border to bottom nav boxes*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li {
        border-bottom: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
    }

    /* Colors/style dropdown box*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    /*allows nav box to use 100% width*/
    nav.sidebar .navbar-collapse, nav.sidebar .container-fluid {
        padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
    }

    /*colors dropdown box text */
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #777;
    }

    /*gives sidebar width/height*/
    nav.sidebar {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -160px;
        float: left;
        z-index: 8000;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

        /*give sidebar 100% width;*/
        nav.sidebar li {
            width: 100%;
        }

        /* Move nav to full on mouse over*/
        nav.sidebar:hover {
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
    /*for hiden things when navbar hidden*/
    .forAnimate {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

/* .....NavBar: Fully showing nav bar..... */

@media (min-width: 1330px) {

    /*Allow main to be next to Nav*/
    .main {
        width: calc(100% - 200px); /*keeps 100% minus nav size*/
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

    /*Show all nav*/
    nav.sidebar {
        margin-left: 0px;
        float: left;
    }
        /*Show hidden items on nav*/
        nav.sidebar .forAnimate {
            opacity: 1;
        }
}

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #CCC;
    background-color: transparent;
}

nav:hover .forAnimate {
    opacity: 1;
}

section {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
/*.btn-primary {
        background: #279989 !important;
        border-color : #279989 !important;
    }
    .navbar-inverse {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
        color : #000000;
    }
    .navbar-brand:hover { 
        background-color: #279989 !important;
        color : #000000;
    }
    .nav .navbar-nav:hover {
        background-color: #279989 !important;
        color : #000000;
    }*/
.navbar-nav {
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    color: #000000;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #777;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #279989 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #ceb7b7;
}

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
        background-color: #279989 !important;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

.navbar-brand a:focus {
    color: red;
}

.navbar-brand a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="active"><a href="../Dashboard/Index">Dashboard<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown  open">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Maestros <span class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="/Faena">Faenas</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Area">Areas</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Proceso">Procesos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Subproceso">Subprocesos</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-divider"><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/ModeloOperativo">Modelo Operativo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Rol">Roles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Peso">Peso de Preguntas</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Maduracion">Nivel de Maduracion</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Dimension">Dimension</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/ProcesoAMSA">Procesos AMSA</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-divider"><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Pregunta">Preguntas</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
```

Y todo funciona bien, pero lo que no he podido lograr es separar las listas.

Quiero que dentro de la lista `Maestros` existan 3 listas despegables distintas.

1) Faenas y dentro contener Faenas, Areas
2) Procesos y dentro contener Proceso y Subproceso
3) Preguntas y dentro contener todas las restantes

He intentado utilizar de boostrap

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  ...
  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Pero no he a resultado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un post que hice en mi blog que soluciona tu problema.
http://blog.furiosojack.com/2017/05/crear-un-dropdown-aninado-o-de-varios.html

Este css es el que hace funcionar la listas una dentro de otra, entonces es necesario tenerlo

```
 .dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

html

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#">Even More..</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">3rd level</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Second level</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
```

Comment: Lo probe! y funciona perfecto, solo como duda, como podria darle el mismo estilo a los `<a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>` que los principales???

Comment: osea solo el color? si es asi y utilizas bootstrap como front-end entonces aplicale la clase button btn btn-default quedando <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="btn btn-default">Hover me for more options</a>

Comment: perfecto,muchas gracias @FuriosoJack

Comment: de nada, tu también me has salvado en android ;)